# PowerBI dashboard on web interface

Tags: sql-server, powerbi

I have developed a Power BI dashboard using PowerBI dashboard client. I do have to present that report in a environment where I won't be having any rights to install new software. What is a way to deploy that report on web so that I can show it to my client.

Note: I have developed that from my local PC database however, if required, I can deploy that on Azure.

Can I show dashboard on web page?

Comment: Did you create your dashboard in excel or Designer tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [**export** your desktop client dashboards/reports](https://support.powerbi.com/knowledgebase/articles/597003-get-data-from-excel-power-bi-desktop-and-csv-fil) as `*.pbix` file or straight away [**publish** to power bi cloud](https://support.powerbi.com/knowledgebase/articles/461278-upload-power-bi-designer-reports).

Once on cloud, you can change the data connection information anytime. Reports structure and dashboard will be unaffected, if both old and new database connections have same database tables/structure.